# Double sided document

Tags: mpdf

I'm having trouble understanding how to create a double sided document with mPDF. Sure, I could create a landscape A3 and then just position everything accordingly. But for text columns that span over pages it think it would be easier to to just be able to define A4 and double sided.

I've tried the **mirrorMargins = true** option but this doesn't do anything. I'm placing an image on each page just for testing. When saving the PDF and viewing it (in preview on mac, *with show as double sided, i.e. this is not a mac preview problem. Side note, PDFs created with mPDF can't open in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC*) I still get a single sided document, i.e. they aren't truly created as a double sided document.

```
$pdfOptions = array(
    'mode'                  => 'utf-8',
    'format'                => 'A4',
    'img_dpi'               => 300,
    'mirrorMargins'         => true,
);
$pdf                    = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( $pdfOptions );
$pdf->WriteHTML( $styles, 1 );
$pdf->WriteHTML( $imageElementFull, 2 );
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML( $imageElementFull, 2 );
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the pages side-by-side in your PDF viewer, use `$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage', 'two');`.

In your example, that would be:

```
$pdfOptions = array(
    'mode'                  => 'utf-8',
    'format'                => 'A4',
    'img_dpi'               => 300,
    'mirrorMargins'         => true,
);
$pdf                    = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( $pdfOptions );

//Set the display mode
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage', 'two');

//Write content to the PDF
$pdf->WriteHTML( $styles, 1 );
$pdf->WriteHTML( $imageElementFull, 2 );
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML( $imageElementFull, 2 );
$pdf->Output();
```

[See the mPDF documentation for more details about this method](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setdisplaymode.html).

Comment: Thank you... It turns out this was more of an issue with math... I.e. 2 pages are just that, two separate pages. Once I added a third page I got what I was expecting, i.e. 1 single page (cover) and 2 pages next to each other. But this answer got me there, so nevertheless, thank you for taking the time to answer the question! : )